# Installing Liberty profile in Vagrant without puppet or chef

Tags: vagrant, websphere-liberty

I am new to Vagrant and I am trying to install Liberty profile in my system. So is there a way to install it without chef, puppet or Docker. Like, a plugin or direct installation to Vagrant. Please help me with it.

Comment: In vagrant you can use shell script to provision your machine e.g:


    'config.vm.define "mytest"  do |mytest|'
      'mytest.vm.provision "shell" do |s|'
        's.path = "path_to_provision_scirpt/provision_script.sh"'
        's.args = "some_args" # add this if you need'
      'end'
    'end'
.

In `provision_script.sh` run steps described in documentation: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/

Comment: I tired to install the server based on the documentation, but am not able to create the server, Here is my provision file   [ apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install openjdk-6-jdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386
pwd
cd /vagrant
java -jar wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.5.4.jar --viewLicenseAgreement x
cd wlp/bin
server create server1
server start server1 ]. I am getting server command not found, Can you help me with it

Comment: You should add this to your question and format it.